# can I change the color of python ttk combobox under windows?

Tags: python, windows, ttk, tcombobox

I got working code under Linux to change the appearance of a TCombobox of Ttk under python 2.7. If I run the code under windows, it wont work. Im aware, that colors and also attributes of the ttk widgets are platform-dependant. Still I cannot figure out how to change the color of either the textarea or the downarrow of the combobox under windows.
The code, which is working under linux is like that:

```
self = Tkinter.Canvas
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('Yellow.TCombobox',background="yellow")
combo = ttk.Combobox(self,width=12,font=("Arial",8),style="Yellow.TCombobox")
```

I tried to find out about which attributes the TCombobox has got under windows by:

```
    print style.layout("TCombobox")
    style.configure("Yellow.TCombobox",fieldbackground="yellow")
    print style.lookup("Yellow.TCombobox", 'fieldbackground')
```

My print output is the following:

```
[('Combobox.field', {'children': [('Combobox.downarrow', {'side':
 'right', 'sticky': 'ns'}), ('Combobox.padding', {'children': 
[('Combobox.focus', {'children':
[('Combobox.textarea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})], 'expand': '1', 'sticky':     
'nswe'})], 'expand': '1', 'sticky': 'nswe'})], 'sticky': 'nswe'})]

yellow
```

However, although the attribute fieldbackground is changed to yellow, the appearance of the combobox does not change.
So, how do I change colors?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late for Sammy but for others I got mine working by putting

```
style.theme_use("alt")
```

after the style is defined and the combobox started working as intended but does alter the look and feel on the widget so might not be ideal solution.

Comment: Any idea if there is a way to inherit from the default also?

Comment: Have a look at the answer j_4321 gave to my question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50834356/ttk-combobox-set-background-colour-programatically-and-dynamically)
He inherits the default and changes it to apply to one box